# Dos Assembly Program hanging during Interrupt

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, dos, dosbox

The following program assembles without error or warning. However, when I run it it displays "ABK" on the top and then hangs the DosBox.
I am using nasm assembler and DosBox.
I write

**nasm eex9_2.asm -o eex9_2.com**

```
        [org 0x100]

        jmp start

oldisr: dd 0
kbisr:  push ax
        push es
        mov ax, 0xb800
        mov es, ax

        xor ax, ax

        in al, 0x60
        mov byte [es:0], 'A'
        mov byte [es:2], 'B'
        mov byte [es:4], 'K'

        mov al, 0x20
        out 0x20, al

        pop es
        pop ax
        iret

start:  xor  ax, ax
        mov  es, ax
        mov  ax, [es:9*4]
        mov  [oldisr], ax
        mov  ax, [es:9*4+2]
        mov  [oldisr+2], ax

        mov  word [es:9*4], kbisr ; store offset at n*4
        mov  [es:9*4+2], cs


        mov dx, start
        add dx, 6
        mov cl, 4
        shr dx, cl
        mov ax, 0x3100
        int 21h
```

Comment: One reason this may hang is that you don't call the original keyboard handler in your new keyboard ISR. Likely your program exits but DOS no longer sees character input.

Comment: It also seems that your paragraph calculation may be a bit off. If you are trying to determine the number of paragraphs to keep resident. `start` is the label at the end of the resident portion which you put in _DX_. You should add 15 to _DX_ and then divide by 16. You only add 6 which may not allocate enough pages. Adding (16-1=15) and then dividing by 16 has the effect of rounding the number of paragraphs up (rather than potentially down)..

Comment: @MichaelPetch I also created listing file. It says 0x2A on start label. Thats why I added only 6.

Comment: Since you are creating a COM file you can replace `mov dx, start
        add dx, 6
        mov cl, 4
        shr dx, cl` with `mov dx, ((start-$$)+0x100+15)>>4` . `$$` is the start of the section which in this case is 0x100. You add back in the origin point of 0x100 and then add an additional (16-1)=15 so the paragraph number is rounded up.

Comment: As a TSR and a COM program with the way you are doing this you would have to keep resident the first 0x100 bytes, and all the bytes in the interrupt routine (up to the `start`) label. The number of paragraphs (a paragraph is 16 bytes) you want to keep has to be rounded up since you don't want a partial paragraph being rounded down and memory being freed that contains part of the interrupt handler. Failure to get this right will create a situation where even a proper interrupt handler will crash when the program is made a TSR.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You mean that we have to make first 100 bytes also part of TSR although we are not using it.

Comment: If you mean the first 256 bytes (0x100) That is correct when dealing with a COM program. The first 256 bytes are the PSP.

Comment: I should point out it is possible to free up the COM programs program environment block and it is also possible to copy all or part of the resident code of the interrupt handler into the possibly unneeded portion of the PSP. If you don't need the resident code to do FCB file access and no longer need the command line parameters you can actually copy code/data to the memory area starting at 0x5C in the PSP. This requires a bit of NASM trickery to pull off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has two problems:

The *smaller* one is the following two lines:

```
mov  word [es:9*4], kbisr
mov  [es:9*4+2], cs
```

If there is some keyboard input received after the first of the two instructions the system will crash because the interrupt handler address is wrong (it is the "old" segment and the "new" offset).

You should do the following:

```
cli
mov  word [es:9*4], kbisr
mov  [es:9*4+2], cs
sti
```

However the *main problem* is the one Michael Petch was writing about:

The operating system uses the interrupt to get keyboard input. If you type:

```
C:\>dir
```

The interrupt will be called 8 times:

- Once when "D" is pressed
- Once when "D" is released
- ...
- Once when the return key is released

Each time when a key is pressed the interrupt will read the key data (as your interrupt does) and write the data to some memory. The operating system (or other programs) will read out the data in the memory and knows that you typed "dir".

If you install your own keyboard interrupt no data will be written to that memory (unless your interrupt does this) so no program can read the keyboard any more!

If you are not interested in the data from the keyboard (the actual key pressed) you can do what Michael Petch suggests:

```
kbisr:  push ax
        push es
        mov ax, 0xb800
        mov es, ax
        mov byte [es:0], 'A'
        mov byte [es:2], 'B'
        mov byte [es:4], 'K'
        pop es
        pop ax
        jmp far [cs:oldisr]
```

(I'm not sure if the last line has the correct syntax because I use GNU assembler which uses another syntax than nasm.)

The last line will jump to the original interrupt which will do ...

- ... the reading of port 0x60
- ... writing 0x20 to port 0x20
- ... writing the keyboard data to the memory (what you don't do)
- ... IRET

If you need to know which key is pressed AND you want the OS to work correctly you'll nearly have no chance...

Comment: Your syntax is right. Actually I want to write my own little keyboard interrupt routine.

Comment: writing the keyboard data to the memory (what you don't do)? How to do this. Where do I have to write the keyboard data? I think it must be some kind of buffer?

Comment: @AhmedBilal The problem is that there is no standard how this memory is structured. The MS-DOS keyboard layout driver (keyb.com) for example replaces the BIOS' complete keyboard handling and uses an own memory area! This means you would have to replace all keyboard-related BIOS functions by your own ones... If you only want the keyboard interrupt to be active while your program runs this is easier: Simply do not call any BIOS/DOS functions accessing the keyboard and restore the original vector before leaving the program.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't think so. Some keys will generate 2 or even more bytes of data. I'm not sure how DosBox behaves but a real keyboard controller would not be able to detect if two reads are done in the same interrupt or in two interrupts. If the timing is not very quick then both bytes of data would be read if you chain the interrupts.